# UITableView delete row and show 'no content' row

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView containing bookmarks. When no bookmarks are present, I'd like to show a default "no bookmarks" row.

The bookmarks are editable. When the last one is deleted, the bookmark row is replaced by the default "[No bookmarks]" row. But Cocoa Touch dislikes this immensely and crashes due to an internal assertion that there should be fewer rows after a delete than there were before.

When I press delete in the screenshot below

[image]

The app crashes with the following error:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Instead of showing this:

[image]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While @Wain advised that you delete a row and insert a row at the same time, I'd like to add that you can *also* use cell reloading to achieve the same effect. The `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` function is sometimes overlooked, but it's quite handy when you need to replace a cell with another type of cell.

In practice, you would do something like this when the table view notifies you of a user deletion:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //Delete the item from the data source first!

        //If there are no more items in the data source array for that section, reload the last remaining row. Otherwise, just delete the row.
        if ([myDataSourceArrayForTheAppropriateSection count] == 0)
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        else
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }
}
```

Like I said, this is an alternative solution that makes more sense to me, and it also has the benefit of using just one animation call.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this worked. I tried @Wain's solution, but it would still crash. The assertion happens inside deleteRowsAtIndexPaths (leaving no opportunity to call insertRowsAtIndexPaths afterwards). Similarly calling insertRowsAtIndexPaths first and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths results in a crash. insertRowsAtIndexPaths has the same assertion in it.

Comment: After some testing I realized this approach actually causes bugs too. After replacing the row using the reload method and then repopulating, you can no longer delete the repopulated rows. See this followup question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321021/uitableview-certain-rows-not-editable

Comment: Hmmm. I've never seen that happen before. You're sure it's *because* of the reloading code?

Answer (score 0):

When you detect that the deletion is the last item to be removed you have some logic to show your default row. When that happens, you can still delete the row but if the row count after that is 1 (because of your default row) you need to insert a row at the same time. You existing detection logic should work fine for this.

---

This all goes in with the delete handling code where you currently delete the last item and the row.

Comment: Sounds like it would work @Wain. What method should this be done in?

Comment: Wain see comment on @architectpianist answer above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using blocks something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //add row here.
    //reload table data
});
```

Comment: How would that solve it? Where do you envision putting the above? Thanks.

Comment: ok so the idea of this code snippet is to enqueue an action at a later time. I imagine you have some thing like if( last row) {then add a row} that is where I would put this code. in place of the then add a row.

Comment: so the way this works is it lets the deletion code run first and at a later moment it adds the row if you put a break point you will notice that the code gets executed at a later time.