# UITableView certain rows not editable

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I've configured a UITableView to be editable. For some reason, when the edit button is pressed, only certain rows are actually editable.

Not all of the red, tappable circles used to delete a row are tappable.

Here is a [Quicktime video demonstrating the problem](http://concept.allegrodynamics.com/tableview_issue.mov).

The same behavior occurs if you swipe the row to delete it (instead of starting with the edit button at the top) - some rows are editable; some are no.

Here is the sequence of events under which I encounter this situation:
1. Populate the tableview (with, say, 2 items)
2. Delete both items
3. Add five items
4. Three of these items will be deletable - the other two (equal to the number initially populating the table) will not be deletable.

I'm a little perplexed. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does your `canEditRowAtIndexPath: / editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` look like?

Comment: I have a the result of canEditRowAtIndexPath logged, and it always returns true. In addition, when it returns false, the behavior is different - the red circle won't appear.

Comment: editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath is not implemented.

Comment: Do you have any gesture recognizer on your table view that could be interfering with touches and swipes?

Comment: No sir, no gesture recognizers.

Comment: @bbrame Could you show some code where you are populating the table? How are you creating the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to class, when you implement eatable view delegate:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
automaticEditControlsDidShow = NO;
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

if (editing) {
    automaticEditControlsDidShow = YES;
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
} else {
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:addRow withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}
}
```

Or try to implement your `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`  method. For Example:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```